# can not get twitter user details in swift

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I am trying to load twitter user details using this code

```
@IBAction func twitterLogin(sender: UIButton) {
    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter) {

        let accountType = self.accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)

        accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(accountType, options: nil, completion: { (granted : Bool, error : NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                 print("Error in getting permission : \(error)")
            } else {
                 if granted {
                    let accounts : NSArray = self.accountStore.accountsWithAccountType(accountType)
                    if accounts.count > 0 {
                        self.twitterAccount = accounts.lastObject as? ACAccount

                        let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json")

                        let parameters : NSDictionary = ["fields": "user_id,screen_name"]

                        let twitterRequest : SLRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook, requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.GET, URL: url, parameters: parameters as [NSObject : AnyObject])
                        twitterRequest.account = self.facebookAccount
                        twitterRequest.performRequestWithHandler({ (responseData : NSData?, urlResponse : NSHTTPURLResponse?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

                        if error != nil {
                            print("Error : \(error)")
                        } else {
//                          print("data : \(responseData)")
                          if let response = responseData {
                            var dict = NSDictionary()
                            do {
                                dict = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                                } catch let error as NSError {
                                    print("Error : \(error)")
                                }
                                print(dict)
                           }
                        }
                        })
                        }
                    } else {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                            self.showAlert(nil, message: "Permission not granted")
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            self.askForSettingsChange("No Twitter Account", message: "There are no Twitter accounts configured. You can add or create Twitter account in Settings")
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
{
    errors =     (
                {
            code = 215;
            message = "Bad Authentication data.";
        }
    );
}
```

Get many examples but cannot get proper solution.
I think that may be problem in api call or may be parameters.
Try to correct but no success

Comment: Seems like you written code for Twitter and accessing Facebook account. Please check your code.
SLServiceTypeFacebook = SLServiceTypeTwitter etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric is sdk which is providing twitter login with  easy authentication via either guest or user login.

[Twitter login using Fabric](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/index.html)

Sample Code written in Swift  [https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/index.html](https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-ios)

If you want to use raw REST calls against the API, follow the OAuth details in developer documentation

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth

Comment: I studied all contents but can not understood where to change my code...I am using social & accounts framework to login with twitter...plz help if you can

Comment: you just have to follow Oauth details to remove this error.Here is link follow each and every step.you will get your solution http://codegerms.com/login-with-twitter-example-with-ios-tutorial-using-oauth/